# Varnish with PHP FastCGI / Change FastCGI server port

Tags: php, cache, varnish, fastcgi

I want to run Magento with Varnish Cache. So far my PHP runs as FastCGI. I am now trying to set up Varnish. And have a probably pretty stupid question.

So as I understand Varnish will listen on port 80 and fetch whatever is missing from my webserver, which should run on port 8080 (or whatever I want). In my case this is FastCGI.

So how do I change the port FastCGI is running on? Or am I missing something / misunderstanding everything?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Varnish cannot connect to FastCGI backend directly. You nee to use your existing webserver for HTTP - FastCGI translation.

So, you need to change your existing webserver to another port, and then use that as the backend in Varnish.